# How to aggregate time for each employee in bi-weekly pay schedule in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-queryset

How to add up time_work for each employee up to 15th of each month?

```
class TimeLog(models.Model):
    employee    = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    start_date  = models.DateTimeField (null=True, blank=True)
    end_date    = models.DateTimeField (null=True, blank=True)
    time_worked = models.DurationField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
# You need to figure a way to configure the dates below but the code is the same
timelog = TimeLog.objects.filter(end_date__range[01/09/2020, 15/09/2020])
employee_time = {}
for log in timelog:
    if timelog.employee not in employee_time:
        employee_time[timelog.employee] = timelog.time_worked
        continue

    employee_time[timelog.employee] += timelog.time_worked
```

Comment: Can you please explain the code from "if timelog.employee not in employee_time:"

Comment: It's saying if we don't contain the employee "Danny" (for example) in employee_time dictionary, we want to add him and assign him a value of his timelog. We have to declare this because if he doesn't exist in the employee_time dictionary we are trying to add a value that doesn't exist (the += operator) and we get an error.

Comment: TypeError expected string or bytes-like object @ timelog = TimeLog.objects.filter(end_date__range=(2020-9-1, 2020-9-15))

Comment: The range needs to be wrapped in []. I don't know if Django will allow such formatting, but you will have to make such adjustments.